# I have started converting wcf service to grpc. How to pass AsyncCallBack data type that is declared in proto file to c# class?

Tags: c#, grpc

In proto file:

```
message Test{
AsyncCallBack call = 1;
}
```

In service.cs:

```
public override async Task<int> BeginWorkStream(IAsyncStreamReader<NewServiceRequest> request, IServerStreamWriter <NewServiceResponse> response, ServerCallContext context)
{
  return Execute(request.Current. 
}
```

I don't find the AsyncCallBack variable here to add.

Comment: Have you declared AsyncCallBack in your protofile?

Comment: Not sure on how to define it proto file. Someone can help?